# Why the CreateTableClient doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am a new azure table user, and I am trying to write something to a table could someone please explain me why the storageAccount.CreateTableClient() doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;




namespace project_3_backend
{
    public class Functions
    {
        private static CloudTable LoanInfo = null;

        private static IConfiguration Configuration;

        public Functions(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public static void WritetoTable()
        {
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetValue<String>("AzureWebjobsStorage");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateTableClient();
            CloudTable table_mortage = tableClient.GetTableReference("LoanInfo");
        }
}
```

Comment: _doesn't work_ isn't really helpful. What doesn't work exactly, do you get null, an exception. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Table Services is now under Cosmos Db:

Install the following nuget packages:

- Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet#install-the-required-nuget-package

Then:

```
public static async Task<CloudTable> CreateTableAsync(string tableName)
  {
    string storageConnectionString = AppSettings.LoadAppSettings().StorageConnectionString;

    // Retrieve storage account information from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(storageConnectionString);

    // Create a table client for interacting with the table service
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient(new TableClientConfiguration());

    Console.WriteLine("Create a Table for the demo");

    // Create a table client for interacting with the table service 
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
    if (await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Created Table named: {0}", tableName);
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Table {0} already exists", tableName);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    return table;
}
```

Probably you can still use old nuget packages to make it work with Azure Storage, but I am afraid you won't have latest version of the packages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet#parse-and-validate-the-connection-details

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting this error is because you're using two different Storage SDKs in your code.

You're using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` which is the older SDK as well as `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` which is the newer one. Currently you're getting a reference for `CloudStorageAccount` from `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` namespace and that does not have a definition for `CloudTableClient` and hence you're getting this error.

One solution is to use `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` as mentioned in the other answer. Going forward this is the recommended way.

Other option is to just use the older SDK (`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`). In that case, you will get `CloudStorageAccount` from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` namespace and that has a definition for `CloudTableClient`.